# Symfony with DataTables translate row entry

Tags: symfony, datatable, datatables, twig, symfony4

I have a set of entries in the database that i saved the names as placeholders in order to be translated afterwards.

> Example:

```
| id | settings_id | settings_name       | value |
| 1  | 1           | value.to.translate1 | 1     |
| 2  | 1           | value.to.translate2 | 2     |
```

I am getting this as a json string to be used with DataTables in twig where I am trying to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#settings').dataTable({
       data: dataSet,
       columns: [
           {"data": "id"},
           {
               "render": function (data, type, row) {
                   return {{ row.settings_name|trans }}; // <---- THE PROBLEM
               }
           },
           {
               "render": function (data, type, row) {
                   var url = '{{ path('admin_settings_values', {'id': app.request.get('id'), 'id': 'settingsId'}) }}';
                   url = url.replace("settingsId", row.id);

                   return '<a href="' + url + '">{{ 'admin.settings.view.values'|trans }}</a>';
               }
           },
```

This obviously is not working. How can I make this translatable in twig? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best option but for now it works:

Inside the controller i did the following:

```
    $aSettingsList = $this->getRepository(Settings::class)->findAllScalar();

    foreach($aSettingsList as $key => $value) {
        $value['name'] = $this->trans($value['name']);
        $aSettingsList[$key] = $value;
    }
```

> query

```
public function findAllScalar()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('s.id', 's.name')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getScalarResult();
}
```

> twig

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#settings').dataTable({
            data: dataSet,
            columns: [
                {"data": "id"},
                {"data": "name"}, // <--- HERE
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        var url = '{{ path('admin_settings_edit', {'id': app.request.get('id'), 'id': 'settingsId'}) }}';
                        url = url.replace("settingsId", row.id);

                        return '<a href="' + url + '">{{ 'admin.settings.view.values'|trans }}</a>';
                    }
                },
            ],
```

Let me know if you have a better solution.